# Cambiar tipo de consulta SQL

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo una tabla que muestra los resultados de mysql mediante una consulta, pero me gustaría poder cambiar el tipo de consulta. Os dejo un ejemplo sencillo.

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM avisos ORDER BY fecha DESC';
```

Necesito que mediante un botón (o algo parecido) se cambie el tipo de consulta a través de una función

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM avisos WHERE tecnico="Manu" ORDER BY fecha DESC';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deberas enviar una variable que luego debe ser atrapada en la consulta ejemplo

```
http://tupagina.com?order=asc
```

debes atrapar la variable **order** y hacer esto

```
$order = $_GET['order'];    
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM avisos ORDER BY fecha '.$order;
```

Comment: Aunque es correcto, esta solución tiene un riesgo de SQL Injection.

Comment: soy un poco novato en php, por ejemplo para transformar esto : $sql = 'SELECT * FROM avisos ORDER BY fecha DESC'; a esto $sql = 'SELECT * FROM avisos WHERE tecnico="Manu" ORDER BY fecha DESC'; con un boton, como lo podría hacer?